# React Hooks setState of an element in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, state, typeerror

How can I update a single element in a state array? Here is the code that I am currently using:

```
const Cars = props => {
  const [cars, setCars] = React.useState(["Honda","Toyota","Dodge"])

  const handleClick1 = () => { setCars[0]("Jeep") }
  const handleClick2 = () => { setCars[1]("Jeep") }
  const handleClick3 = () => { setCars[2]("Jeep") }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleClick1}>{cars[0]}</button>
      <button onClick={handleClick2}>{cars[1]}</button>
      <button onClick={handleClick3}>{cars[2]}</button>
    </div>
  )
};
```

When I click one of the rendered buttons, I get `Uncaught TypeError: setCars[0] is not a function at handleClick1`.

I know how to do this in a React Class, but how can I do this with React Hooks?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I suggest you map through your `cars` in order to render them - this is just overall a million times easier.  From there you can apply an `onClick` handler to each button..

Furthermore, you should not mutate state like you are - always make a copy of state first, update the copy, then set your new state with the updated copy.

***Edit:*** one thing that slipped my mind before was adding a `key` to each item when you are `map`ping over an array. This should be standard practice.

```js
const { useState } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

const Cars = props => {
  const [cars, setCars] = useState(["Honda", "Toyota", "Dodge"]);

  const updateCars = (value, index) => () => {
    let carsCopy = [...cars];
    carsCopy[index] = value;
    setCars(carsCopy);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {cars && cars.map((c, i) => 
        <button key={`${i}_${c}`} onClick={updateCars("Jeep", i)}>{c}</button>
      )}
      <pre>{cars && JSON.stringify(cars, null, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};

render(<Cars />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should correct these lines to spot the source of error

```
const handleClick1 = () => { setCars[0]("Jeep") }
```

into

```
const handleClick1 = () => { cars[0]="Jeep"; setCars(cars); }
```

Comment: you are mutating state variables. It's "no-no" in React world. Re-rendering probably will run anyway(it least for class-based component `setState` re-render even if no changes), but once you pass this state as a prop to some child you man go in trouble.

Comment: yes i see your point, but considering the that is not the numero uno issue in question its some times better to keep it simple: Uncaught TypeError